# Import timestamp in proto file of protobuf for GRPC

Tags: protocol-buffers, grpc

I am trying to use gRPC and using the exchange message format as protobuf.
I wanted to add timestamp field inside my message.But i don't know the right way to add the import statement in proto file. I  am using Golang so I need an output as .pb.go

Comment: Even if you've added library for timestamp as mentioned in below answers, be sure to import the package "C:\Program Files\protoc-3.13.0-win64\include" as it contains libraries related to timestamp. Faced error because of path problem thought to share it.

Answer (score 31):

Make sure to import in your proto file:

```
import "google/protobuf/timestamp.proto";
```

And use the type for you variable like:

```
google.protobuf.Timestamp time_name = 1;
```

Answer (score 2):

In your proto file:

```
import "google/protobuf/timestamp.proto"
```

Based on the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/go-generated#well-known-types), that should be all that's necessary.

Answer (score 0):

You can import timestamp from the [ptypes package](https://github.com/golang/protobuf/blob/master/ptypes/timestamp/timestamp.pb.go): in the standard Go Protobuf repo.

```
import (
    "github.com/golang/protobuf/ptypes/timestamp"
)
```

Answer (score -1):

Grpc does not have a timestamp AFAIK.
I usually use the Unix Epoch - the go function

```
 Unix(sec int64, nsec int64)
```

and

```
func (t Time) Unix() int64
```

is your fried